# For the following mysql query I got an output. But how to modify the query so that I get results for a range of date

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select hotel.*, hotels.type 
from pe,se 
where p.hotel_Id = s.S_Id 
  and Type="";
```

The output I got is

```
 pid     SId     PName     PPlan     PMethod     PDate     numberOfParents     SType    
 ---------------------  ----------  -------------------------  -------------------------  ---------------------------  -------------------------  ------------------  ------------ 
 4                      2           kjbkjbjkbk                 jkbjbkbl                   lkblknl                      10/5/2012                  234                 abc       
 6                      2           dfvrvt                     rvrtv                      rvrtvrt                      1/1/2012                   3                   abc       
 9                      2           er
```

Now my problem is I want query so that my output will be in a such way that the data are for a range of dates. For eg, 08/09/2012 to 10/12/2012.

Separately I could write the mysql query for a date range using >= and <=. But I could not combine that date range part in the present query. Please help me.

Comment: Where do you store your date?

Comment: date column is part of parentengagement table. In the query it will be part of where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using parenthesis can help make your `WHERE` clause clear when dealing with date ranges:

```
SELECT p.*
  , s.Site_Type 
FROM parentengagement AS p
INNER JOIN site AS s ON p.Site_Id = s.Site_Id 
  AND s.Site_Type = 'County'
  AND
  (
     p.Parent_Engagement_Date >= '2012-08-09'
       AND p.Parent_Engagement_Date <= '2012-10-12'
  )
```

I also recommend using the `INNER JOIN` syntax instead of `FROM table1, table2`
There is a good [**visual representation about joins.**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

**Update From the comments:** The OP would like to sum numberOfparents for each site.

```
SELECT s.Site_Type 
   , SUM(p.NumberOfParents)
FROM parentengagement AS p
INNER JOIN site AS s ON p.Site_Id = s.Site_Id 
  AND s.Site_Type = 'County'
  AND
  (
     p.Parent_Engagement_Date >= '2012-08-09'
       AND p.Parent_Engagement_Date <= '2012-10-12'
  )
GROUP BY s.Site_Type
```

Comment: That worked great. Is it possible to make sum of all "numberOfparents" column whose site type is county.

Comment: You are really a genius. Using inner join will just give intersection , right? May I know how the query could be modified using inner join. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I kindly request you to put the new query as a comment and not to modify the earlier one.So that later if I come back here I can understand it step by step modificaitons done.

Comment: @AarthiMsincs Yes, it is. You would need to know what you want to use to sum with. Would you sum per site, or another criteria? This is probably also best in a different question so that the answers are clear for each part of what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I would like to sum for a given data range and for a given site type.

Comment: @AarthiMsincs I have updated my answer here to reflect your sum question in the comments.  Since StackOverflow is a Q&A Site, in the future it would be best to open a new question for the `SUM` so that way each question/answer can be focused to one specific problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. If possible, I request you to give me your email id to aarthimsincs@yahoo.com. I would like to contact you regarding my SQL doubts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to run the same query but limit it for a date range, you should be able to do that in the same query thusly:

```
select parentengagement.*, site.Site_Type 
from parentengagement,site 
where 
    parentengagement.Site_Id = site.Site_Id and 
    site.Site_Type="County" and
    parentengagement.Parent_Engagement_Date > '2012-10-30' and
    parentengagement.Parent_Engagement_Date <= '2012-10-31'
```